# Select Option fetch data to label using ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I tried fetching the data after selecting an `accountnumber` using ajax it did work but after selecting once I can't select again. I've been trying some solutions but it didn't work.

AccountController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $AM= new AM();
    $AM->setConnection('AM');
    $key= '';
    $getData = $AM->where('Accountnumber',Auth::user()->AccountNum)->get();
    foreach($getData as $row){
        $key= $row->key;
    }


    $getAMData = $AM->where('key',$key)
                    ->select('Accountnumber')
                    ->get();

    $ci= $AM->where('Accountnumber',Auth::user()->AccountNum)
                            ->select('Accountnumber', 'cn', 'ca','ct','accountstatus')
                            ->get();
    return view('account')->with('getAMData',$getAMData)->with('ci',$ci);
}

// Methods

public function fetch(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $AM= new AM();
        $AM->setConnection('AM');

        $getData = $AM->where('Accountnumber',$request->Accountnumber)->get();
        foreach($getData as $row){
            $key= $row->key;
        }

        $getAMData = $AM->where('key',$key)
                    ->select('Accountnumber')
                    ->get();

        $ci= $AccountMaster->where('Accountnumber',$request->Accountnumber)
                            ->select('Accountnumber', 'cn', 'ca','ct','accountstatus')
                            ->get();
        return view('partials._fetch')->with('getAMData',$getAMData)->with('ci',$ci);
    }
}
```

ajax.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accountnum').change(function(){
        var Accountnumber = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/fetch",
            method: "GET",
            data: {Accountnumber:Accountnumber},
            success:function(data){
                $('#showbill').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

account.blade.php

```
        <div class="container-fluid col-sm-12">
            <h3><b> Account </b></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid py-4 col-sm-12" id="showbill">
                @include('partials._fetch')
        </div>
```

I think my problem would be on my controller, maybe the fetch method is not right. anyone can help me with this? Thank you!

_fetch.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        @if(count($getAMData) > 0)
        <select class="form-control form-control-md" id="accountnum" name="accountnum">
                <option value="" selected></option>
                @foreach($getAMData as $row)
                    <option value="{{ $row->Accountnumber }}">{{ $row->Accountnumber }}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
        @else
                <p></p>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 py-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            @if(count($ci) > 0 )
                @foreach ($ci as $row )
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <label>Account Number:</label> <label><strong>{{ $row->Accountnumber }}</strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <label>Name:</label> <label><strong>{{ $row->cn}}</strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <label> Address:</label> <label><strong>{{ $row->ca}}</strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <label>Type:</label> <label><strong>{{ $row->ct}}</strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <label>Account Status:</label> <label><strong>{{ $row->ct}}</strong></label>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <p>NO DATA FOUND</p>
            @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <table class="table table-responsive-md table-hover ">
            <thead style="text-align: center;" class="bg-warning ">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">(MW)</th>
                <th scope="col">Morning (0001H to 1200H)</th>
                <th scope="col">Afternoon (1201H to 1800)</th>
                <th scope="col">Evening (1801 to 2400)</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"></th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using the same concept with the paginate using ajax well it didn't turn out to be what I expected haha

Comment: It gives me the same effect. Also forgot to mention I use two database and two tables for this

Comment: can not select again means that you can only change it once? and second time the content does not change at all?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for solutions but they use `append` which is I'm avoiding.

Comment: any error in the browser console?

Comment: There are no errors found.

Comment: can you change `$('#showbill').html(data);` to `console.log(data)` and try to select multiple times to see the console if you have the correct result?

Comment: yes I did got the correct results. its just that the content doesn't change on the second time, also no errors found.

Comment: and if you change from `$('#showbill').html(data);` to `$('#showbill').html(Accountnumber);` what happens?

Comment: I get the `Accountnumber` only, not the whole data

Comment: @AndySong okay so I tried putting my id `showbill`  to the `_fetch.blade.php` where it shows my data , and it worked , the problem is where to put the `showbill` `id` , I put it on the `account.blade.php` where I included the `_fetch.blade.php`. so the problem I'm having right now for solving my other problem is that I get two results to the datas I want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is my solution to this problem. Instead of including the `Select Option` I put it inside my `account.blade.php` so that it wont regenerate two select options.